# Finding the derivative of $x + y = x^y$

Tags: derivatives

I was solving a previous year question paper of an entrance exam and got stuck in this question

Find the derivative of:

$x + y = x^y$      with respect to $x$

I tried taking similar terms to one side then taking $x$ common but couldn't proceed further.

Comment: It would help to show the equations you got from your efforts so far.

Comment: It would help us to know some more about this problem.  We are taking the derivative with respect to what?  Is there any required format for the answer?  What level of mathematics is the question from?  These sorts of details can help us narrow down an answer for you.  I'm assuming from my experience that this is an implicit differentiation with respect to $x$ and that $y$ is assumed to be a function of $x$, for an entry level calculus course.  If instead it is about partial derivatives, or something more advanced, my answer would be worthless.

Comment: Partial derivatives?

Comment: I edited the question...no the question was to find the equation of the normal at the intersection of this curve and x axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: use implicit differentiation.

And remember: $x^y = e^{y\ln x}$. Chain rule.